# Android Export application using ProGuard

Tags: android, export, proguard

Whenever I export an Android application using ProGuard, I get the following error message:

> @C:\xxxx\xxxx~1\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\android_7813736973653258335.pro (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I have been trying hard to find out the issue but nothing is working out.

Comment: Why do you have an '@' in front of your drive letter?

Comment: that was an error shown in error console

Comment: I am getting same error, whole day is wasted on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be sorted out by using proguard 4.6 and also the name of workspace should not contain any spaces. 
The proguard folder in android sdk windows folder should be replaced with proguard 4.6

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the path to your project or the path you are exporting the file to does not have any of the following special characters `\\ \\ / [ ] : | < > + ; = . ? "`. Also make sure there are no trailing or leading spaces in either of the paths.

Comment: I am not giving any paths, i am trying to export the android application directly from eclipse.

Comment: yes but I believe you still have to specify a destination for the exported file.

Comment: where exactly do i need to specify it?

Comment: On the third screen where it asks you to specify a destination for the apk file.

Comment: i was exporting the apk to a folder and that path did not contain any spaces, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7, Eclipse Juno, using ADT 22.2.1.

The original Proguard was 4.6.
I had to upgrade to 4.10 to solve this problem.