# Initializing project state error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently get this error in my Error log. I have no problems installing my app on my phone, works fine, but still I get this error. What does this mean?

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Project.<init>(Project.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Project.create(Project.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.createProject(LintClient.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.getProject(LintClient.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver$LintClientWrapper.getProject(LintDriver.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.registerProjectFile(LintDriver.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.computeProjects(LintDriver.)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you able to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

Had you googled it? It appears to be a problem present in different scenarios, and as the message suggests, most of the times is related to an invalid path. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615937/android-export-application-using-proguard), @Jeshurun's answer, maybe it can help you.